# Timing moving figures

Tags: animation

I have an animation that simulates rectangles going through a line.

[image]

**1. I wonder if it is possible to time the events of each figure.**

I separated the rectangles by color for easy recognition of each.

The count could start with the passage of the first rectangle.

The simulation was not created by Mathematica Software. Was obtained from the After Effects software. I'm still creating the code

One can also use this mathematica generated animation:

```
SeedRandom@1
speed = RandomReal[{1, 2}, 5];
dat = Table[
   ColorNegate@
    Binarize@
     Rasterize[
      Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 80}, {100, 80}}], Thickness[.03], 
        Table[Line[{{-10 + 20 x, 10 + t speed[[x]]}, {-10 + 20 x, 
            25 + t speed[[x]]}}], {x, 5}]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}], 
      ImageSize -> {200, 200}], {t, 80}];

ListAnimate@dat
```

Comment: Maybe related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59225/how-to-track-objects-in-video).

Comment: It's an interesting question and I'm working on it, but can you reduce the gif a bit and aviod multiple runs? After imported your gif I found out that this animation was ran for multiple times......`Part` will be ugly

Comment: @Shutao Tang I was never programmer. I am a mechanical engineer. And as the trend is to know programming want to have good knowledge to help my son in the future.

Comment: @Wjx That cool you have edited, but just modify the animation.

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho I'm working on it when I have spare time, but the motion blur created by AE is a great barrier, so I modified it into several rasterized graphics.

Comment: OK. Tomorrow I will compare with other questions found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a start. In the following:

- `Manipulate` is used to remove the top(digits and line)
- as the labeling of the components crosses `fun` relabels
- the animated gif was by exporting `vis[]` (what is posted  is downsampled to allow posting)
- what is displayed are frames where there are discernible two objects
- exponential moving average smoothing was used to smooth the "wobble" of the centroid
- obviously this can be rescaled by whatever the display duration is

  ```
  imlist = Import["http://i.imgur.com/LDQfqep.gif"];
  Manipulate[ImageTake[imlist[[1]], -p], {p, 10, 1000}];
  cm[i_] := 
  ComponentMeasurements[Dilation[ColorNegate@Binarize[i], 10], 
  "Centroid"]
  cn = cm /@ (ImageTake[#, -235] & /@ imlist);
  pick = Pick[imlist, Length[#] == 2 & /@ cn];
  pc = Pick[cn, Length[#] == 2 & /@ cn];
  fun[u_] := 
  If[Abs[(1 /. u)[[1]] - pc[[1, 1, 2, 1]]] < 20, u, 
  u /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}]
  pcf = fun /@ pc;
  dis[u_] := EuclideanDistance[#, u[[1]]] & /@ u;
  vis[] := Module[{pts1 = 1 /. pcf, pts2 = 2 /. pcf, an, d, v, lp, if1, 
  if2, sp},
  an = MapThread[
  Show[#3, 
    Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.04], Point@#1, Blue, 
      Point@#2}]] &, {pts1, pts2, pick}];
  d = dis /@ {pts1, pts2};
  v = Transpose@d;
  lp = MapIndexed[
  ListPlot[d, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[0.04], Red, 
      Point[{#2[[1]], v[[#2[[1]], 1]]}], Green, 
      Point[{#2[[1]], v[[#2[[1]], 2]]}]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, ImageSize -> 300] &, v, 1];
  {if1, if2} = 
  Interpolation /@ (ExponentialMovingAverage[#, 0.1] & /@ d);
  sp = Plot[{D[if1[x], x], D[if2[x], x]}, {x, 1, 114}, 
  Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, ImageSize -> 300];
  MapThread[Framed@Row[{#1, Column[{#2, sp}]}] &, {an, lp}]
  ]
  ```

[image]